# Loop through array and generate Gulp tasks

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, gulp

Im trying to generate my gulp tasks instead of statically writing them .I would like to loop through an array and generate gulp tasks based on the item in the array.

Something like this , any help will be appreciated !

```
var brands  = ['google','facebook','twitter']


brands.forEach(function (brand) {
  gulp.task(brand, function() {
    return gulp.src('./'+ brand + '.scss')
       .pipe(rename('var.scss'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./styles/tmp'));
  })
})
```

Comment: This looks reasonable to me. What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry i tried with a for loop previously which didnt work. This does seem to work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It is a closure issue. The problem is that the variable references within that function you are passing to `gulp.task()` in your case 'brand' should be different from the variable in

```
gulp.task(OtherVariableNameThanBrand, [brand, 'scripts']);
```

A solution for that is :

```
var brands  = ['google','facebook','twitter'];
var style = 'style-';
var styleBrands =[];

brands.forEach(function (brand) {
  gulp.task(brand, function() {
    return gulp.src('./'+ brand + '.scss')
        .pipe(rename('var.scss'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./styles/tmp'));
  })
});

brands.forEach(function(brand) {
  gulp.task(style + brand, [brand, 'scripts']);
  styleBrands.push(style + brand);
});

gulp.task('default', styleBrands);
```

For more details read about [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp)